# Draw transparent holes in a texture/plain color

Tags: c++, opengl, drawing, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm running into a problem and I don't know what is the best practise for it. I have a background that moves upward, which is in fact "slices" that moves toghether, as if the screen was splitted in 4-5 parts horizontally. I need to be able to draw a hole (circle) in the background (see-through), at a specified position which will change dynamically at each frame or so.

Here is how I generate a zone, I don't think there's much of a problem there:

```
// A 'zone' is simply the 'slice' of ground that moves upward. There's about 4 of
// them visible on screen at the same time, and they are automatically generated by
// a method irrelevant to the situation. Zones are Sprites.
// ---------
void LevelLayer::Zone::generate(LevelLayer *sender) {

    // [...]

    // Make a background for the zone
    Sprite *background = this->generateBackgroundSprite();
    background->setPosition(_contentSize.width / 2, _contentSize.height / 2);
    this->addChild(background, 0);
}
```

This is the *Zone::generateBackgroundSprite()* method:

```
// generates dynamically a new background texture
Sprite *LevelLayer::Zone::generateBackgroundSprite() {

    RenderTexture *rt = RenderTexture::create(_contentSize.width, _contentSize.height);
    rt->retain();

    Color4B dirtColorByte = Color4B(/*initialize the color with bytes*/);
    Color4F dirtColor(dirtColorByte);
    rt->beginWithClear(dirtColor.r, dirtColor.g, dirtColor.b, dirtColor.a);

    // [Nothing here yet, gotta learn OpenGL m8]

    rt->end();

    // ++++++++++++++++++++
    // I'm just testing clipping node, it works but the FPS get significantly lower.
    // If I lock them to 60, they get down to 30, and if I lock them there they get
    // to 20 :(
    // Also for the test I'm drawing a square since ClippingNode doesn't seem to
    // like circles...
    DrawNode *square = DrawNode::create();
    Point squarePoints[4] = { Point(-20, -20), Point(20, -20), Point(20, 20), Point(-20, 20) };
    square->drawPolygon(squarePoints, 4, Color4F::BLACK, 0.0f, Color4F(0, 0, 0, 0));
    square->setPosition(0, 0);

    // Make a stencil
    Node *stencil = Node::create();
    stencil->addChild(square);

    // Create a clipping node with the prepared stencil
    ClippingNode *clippingNode = ClippingNode::create(stencil);
    clippingNode->setInverted(true);
    clippingNode->addChild(rt);

    Sprite *ret = Sprite::create();
    ret->addChild(clippingNode);

    rt->release();
    return ret;
}
```

**
So I'm asking you guys, what would you do in such a situation? Is what I am doing a good idea? Would you do it in another more imaginative way?

PS This is a rewrite of a little app I made for iOS (I want to port it to Android), and I was using MutableTextures in the Objective-C version (it was working). I'm just trying to see if there's a better way using RenderTexture, so I can dynamically create background images using OpenGL calls.

---

### EDIT (SOLUTION)

I wrote my own simple fragment shader that "masks" the visible parts of a texture (the background) based on the visible parts of another texture (the mask). I have an array of points that determine where my circles are on the screen, and in the `update` method I draw them to a RenderTexture. I then take the generated texture and use it as the mask I pass to the shader.

This is my shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform sampler2D u_alphaMaskTexture;

void main() {

    float maskAlpha = texture2D(u_alphaMaskTexture, v_texCoord).a;
    float texAlpha = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord).a;
    float blendAlpha = (1.0 - maskAlpha) * texAlpha; // Show only where mask is not visible

    vec3 texColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord).rgb;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(texColor, blendAlpha);

    return;
}
```

init method:

```
bool HelloWorld::init() {

    // [...]

    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();

    // Load and cache the custom shader
    this->loadCustomShader();

    // 'generateBackgroundSlice()' creates a new RenderTexture and fills it with a
    // color, nothing too complicated here so I won't copy-paste it in my edit
    m_background = Sprite::createWithTexture(this->generateBackgroundSprite()->getSprite()->getTexture());
    m_background->setPosition(visibleSize.width / 2, visibleSize.height / 2);
    this->addChild(m_background);

    m_background->setShaderProgram(ShaderCache::getInstance()->getProgram(Shader_AlphaMask_frag_key));
    GLProgram *shader = m_background->getShaderProgram();
    m_alphaMaskTextureUniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader->getProgram(), "u_alphaMaskTexture");
    glUniform1i(m_alphaMaskTextureUniformLocation, 1);

    m_alphaMaskRender = RenderTexture::create(m_background->getContentSize().width,
                                              m_background->getContentSize().height);
    m_alphaMaskRender->retain();

    // [...]
}
```

loadCustomShader method:

```
void HelloWorld::loadCustomShader() {

    // Load the content of the vertex and fragement shader
    FileUtils *fileUtils = FileUtils::getInstance();
    string vertexSource = ccPositionTextureA8Color_vert;
    string fragmentSource = fileUtils->getStringFromFile(
                            fileUtils->fullPathForFilename("Shader_AlphaMask_frag.fsh"));

    // Init a shader and add its attributes
    GLProgram *shader = new GLProgram;
    shader->initWithByteArrays(vertexSource.c_str(), fragmentSource.c_str());

    shader->bindAttribLocation(GLProgram::ATTRIBUTE_NAME_POSITION, GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION);
    shader->bindAttribLocation(GLProgram::ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEX_COORD, GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_TEX_COORDS);
    shader->link();
    shader->updateUniforms();

    ShaderCache::getInstance()->addProgram(shader, Shader_AlphaMask_frag_key);

    // Trace OpenGL errors if any
    CHECK_GL_ERROR_DEBUG();
}
```

update method:

```
void HelloWorld::update(float dt) {

    // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    // Create the mask texture from the points in the m_circlePos array
    GLProgram *shader = m_background->getShaderProgram();

    m_alphaMaskRender->beginWithClear(0, 0, 0, 0); // Begin with transparent mask

    for (vector<Point>::iterator it = m_circlePos.begin(); it != m_circlePos.end(); it++) {

        // draw a circle on the mask
        const float radius = 40;
        const int resolution = 20;
        Point circlePoints[resolution];

        Point center = *it;
        center = Director::getInstance()->convertToUI(center); // OpenGL has a weird coordinates system
        float angle = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < resolution; i++) {

            float x = (radius * cosf(angle)) + center.x;
            float y = (radius * sinf(angle)) + center.y;
            angle += (2 * M_PI) / resolution;

            circlePoints[i] = Point(x, y);
        }

        DrawNode *circle = DrawNode::create();
        circle->retain();
        circle->drawPolygon(circlePoints, resolution, Color4F::BLACK, 0.0f, Color4F(0, 0, 0, 0));
        circle->setPosition(Point::ZERO);
        circle->visit();
        circle->release();
    }

    m_alphaMaskRender->end();

    Texture2D *alphaMaskTexture = m_alphaMaskRender->getSprite()->getTexture();
    alphaMaskTexture->setAliasTexParameters(); // Disable linear interpolation
    // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    shader->use();
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, alphaMaskTexture->getName());
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might want to look at is framebuffers, i'm not too familiar with the mobile API for OpenGL but I'm sure you should have access to framebuffers.

An idea of what you might want to try is to do a first pass where you render the circles's that you want to set to alpha on your background into a new framebuffer texture, then you can use this texture as an alpha map on your pass for rendering your background. So basically when you render your circle you might set the value in the texture to 0.0 for the alpha channel otherwise to 1.0, when rendering you can then set the alpha channel of the fragment to the same value as the alpha of texture of the first pass' of the rendering process.

You can think of it as a the same idea as a mask. But just using another texture.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: So if I understand correctly, pass one I update the circles positions/color in an alpha map, pass two I use this map to generate the background?

Comment: Almost yes, you wont use the alpha map to generate the background, but more to determine which parts of the background will be alpha/transparent and which parts wont be.

Comment: Determining like iterating over the alpha map, and if the value is 0 don't draw the pixel of the background? How could one do this with OpenGL?

Comment: So if you were using a custom fragment shader, you would be able to bind your alpha map as a texture for your shader, and then when your shader is drawing you would sample the alpha values from the texture using the texture coordinates of the object that you are rendering. When you render your circle into the alpha map, you will need to write a separate passthrough fragment shader for that pass. I'm not sure how the specifics will work though of creating and binding custom shader programs in cocos2d, but this is pretty much the theory of how you would do it if you wrote using openGL API onlly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and will edit the OP with updates later :)

Comment: Cool, remember to give me an upvote or accept the answer if it helped :) And goodluck!